# Drop test db in django after running each test file

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

I have two different tests in my `app/tests/` directory:

`app/tests/tests.py` and now I have added `app/tests/tests_new.py`

Running the tests individually do not throw any error but if I run them together the older file `tests.py` fails some tests as the values are getting altered.

Any idea why is this happening ? Do I need to drop my test database before running the other tests ?

Comment: We don't know anything about your tests. You should probably post your code.

Comment: One has to be a wizard to know what you mean, I would try to be more specific :P